# How can we retrieve existing subscriptions in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

This is the call I'm trying:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
```

This results in the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "QueryNotSupported",
        "message": "The query is not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "8b2f2137-51ed-498d-9fbb-bc0a29c509da",
            "date": "2018-01-27T14:56:01"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK to make the actual call:

```
var subscriptions = await graphServiceClient.Subscriptions.Request().GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to retrieve a list of all existing [subscriptions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription). You need to know the `subscriptionId` for a given subscription before you can `GET`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` a subscription.

Keep in mind that subscriptions are by nature temporary resources. Unless that application that requested the subscription renews it, a given subscription will generally automatically expire within 3 days.

Comment: Thanks @Marc LaFleur for your quick reply